# VBA enumeration to avoid copy/paste

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm not sure how to name this, so feel free to update if you can make it more descriptive.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a very repetitive code that has a very predictive pattern for variables that would make each instance different.

```
'Make sure decimal character is ","

Call SetLocalSetting(LOCALE_SDECIMAL, ",")


'_01 -------------------------------------------------------------

qty_01 = Val(ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text)

'qty_01 is now ready to be used for calculations. Next is price_01.

price_01 = ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(2, 3).Range.Text
price_01 = Replace(price_01, ",", ".")
price_01 = Format(Val(price_01), "##,##0.00")

'price_01 is now ready to be used for calculations. Next are price_01_cro and price_01_eng.

price_01_cro = price_01
price_01_eng = price_01
price_01_eng = Replace(price_01_eng, ",", "decSym")
price_01_eng = Replace(price_01_eng, ".", "thoSym")
price_01_eng = Replace(price_01_eng, "decSym", ".")
price_01_eng = Replace(price_01_eng, "thoSym", ",")

'price_01_cro and price_01_eng are now ready to be used for presentation.


'_02 -------------------------------------------------------------

qty_02 = Val(ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(3, 2).Range.Text)

'qty_02 is now ready to be used for calculations. Next is price_02.

price_02 = ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(3, 3).Range.Text
price_02 = Replace(price_02, ",", ".")
price_02 = Format(Val(price_02), "##,##0.00")

'price_02 is now ready to be used for calculations. Next are price_02_cro and price_02_eng.

price_02_cro = price_02
price_02_eng = price_02
price_02_eng = Replace(price_02_eng, ",", "decSym")
price_02_eng = Replace(price_02_eng, ".", "thoSym")
price_02_eng = Replace(price_02_eng, "decSym", ".")
price_02_eng = Replace(price_02_eng, "thoSym", ",")

'price_02_cro and price_02_eng are now ready to be used for presentation.
```

And it goes on and on 11 times. Is there any way that is more convenient instead of copying the same thing over and over, and changing the numbers?

Btw, this is my continued effort of building the invoice generator. This is why I had to employ some hacks in order to counter Word's oddness when handling decimal characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to test this comprehensively without a better idea of the data you're manipulating, but what about setting up your variables as arrays, and iterating through? It would look something like this:

```
Call SetLocalSetting(LOCALE_SDECIMAL, ",")
Dim qty(0 To 10) As Variant
Dim price(0 To 10) As Variant
Dim price_cro(0 To 10) As Variant
Dim price_eng(0 To 10) As Variant

For inum = 0 To 10

qty(inum) = Val(ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(inum + 1, 2).Range.Text)
price(inum) = ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(inum + 1, 3).Range.Text
price(inum) = Replace(price(inum), ",", ".")
price(inum) = Format(Val(price(inum)), "##,##0.00")
price_cro(inum) = price(inum)
price_eng(inum) = price(inum)
price_eng(inum) = Replace(price_eng(inum), ",", "decSym")
price_eng(inum) = Replace(price_eng(inum), ".", "thoSym")
price_eng(inum) = Replace(price_eng(inum), "decSym", ".")
price_eng(inum) = Replace(price_eng(inum), "thoSym", ",")

Next
```

Comment: That's almost it! But what about `qty(inum)` and `price(inum)` cell values? For example, `price(inum)` should continue with `(2, 3)`, `(3, 3)`, `(4, 3)`, `(5, 3)` and so on. How would you set that up?

Comment: I altered this so that the cell rows are inum + 2, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yup! That's it, except that you need to put inum +1 for the cell rows. Thanks!!